# How to: Re-send an http request when using async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is there a way to resend an HttpRequest when using the async pipe in the template like this?

```js
myObservable$ = this.http.get('api');
```

```html
<div *ngFor='let item of myObservable$ | async'>{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need emit a new value to `Observable`, if you need refetch data by specific event, you can put the event to `Observable` and use `switchMap` for trigger fetching:

```
event$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

myObservable$ = this.event$.pipe(
  switchMapTo(this.http.get('api'))
);

refetchData() {
  this.event$.next();
}
```

Comment: I would also move the event$.next() on the event itself in the template. This is also what I had in mind when I asked the question, and it seems like the only efficient solution to a reactive architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Using `async` pipe is a very convenient way to deal with Observables, because it manages unsubscribing for you. Meaning, that if `myObservable$` reference changes, ChangeDetection will be triggered and `async` will unsubscribe current subscription and subscribe to another. So you can simply reassign new value `myObservable$` and `HttpRequest` will be sent again.

*test it out yourself:*

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => this.myObservable$ = this.http.get('another-endpoint'), 2000)
}
```

Comment: Although a good workaround, I think this approach violates the reactive pattern, which should be used when working with async pipe

Comment: Why would you think so? IMO is a legit way

Comment: Reassigning the observable is imperative, not declarative. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Bogdan B Declarative programming means you express **what** you would like to do, while leaving the **how** to the language or framework. Imperative programming means you tell it step by step how to do something. Variable reassignment doesn't have anything to do with declarative or imperative programming. One great example of declarative programming is the SQL language

Comment: I dont think reassigning a variable in general is either declarative or imperative. By reassigning to a new Observable we do just that. And rest of the logic is being done without our interference - `async` does the work for us, we don't need to give any more instructions. So for this code snippet it appears to be even more declarative

Comment: Dont think reassigning is good. If yoo have subscribers then existing subscribers will not subscribe to new stream and they will remain subscribed to previous stream.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best practice. The async pipe is meant to be used with streams, using it with trigger observables such as http calls can have unwanted side effects. I suggest putting the http call in a service, and subscribing in your component. If there's a specific reason you want to use the async pipe, I suggest having a separate BehaviorSubject and doing something like this....

```
_myBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
myBehaviorSubject$ = this._myBehaviorSubject.asObservable();

myObservable$ = this.http.get('api').pipe(tap(items => this._myBehaviorSubject.push(items)));
```

Then, in your component, you can subscribe to this every time you want to make an http call, and in your html template, subscribe to myBehaviorSubject$ using the async pipe.

Comment: Most examples of http calls on Angular docs are made using an observable and async pipe. Why would it be bad practice if I want fresh data, but I also want Angular to take care of unsubscribing and having a reactive architecture.